How common is it for customers with connecting flights to be routed through immigration check?
On most flights I've taken, when landing at an international airport, in a country that I won't be visiting and isn't my final destination, I can just debark the plane and stay in the international terminal and then board another plane. It's only if I leave the international part that I have to pass through immigration.
But on a recent flight, all passengers who debarked were sent through one route that only led to immigration. Some of the passengers became very aggravated, refusing to cooperate with the officials who wanted to look at the passports, take photographs & fingerprints, as they said they were just passing through to their other flight.
Is that a common practice in some countries to require everyone to be processed through customs, even if they have connecting flights to destinations outside that country? Did the passengers have any right to refuse it?

Very common, depending on the country you've landed in. You'll always do it in the US, for example

"Did the passengers have any right to refuse it?" That would depend entirely on the laws of the country where it took place.  Unless you identify that country, the question isn't answerable.  But the answer is most likely no.

In maybe 2010 or so I flew Beijing - Sydney - NZ. We flew on the same plane throughout. They made us getoff the aircraft and take all our carryon baggage with us and checked us back on through security.

This is standard procedure in the US and Canada (and a few smaller countries) but unusual in most others. If you can add the location, we can much better comment in what might have happened there.

@Midavalo "Very common" needs a citation. In the US, yes. In most others, no. The US isn't the world, just as a gentle reminder :)

@Mayou36 Can you source your "most"?  And I'm not from the US, so am quite aware the US isn't the world.

@Midavalo, there's a bit of ironie in my statement ;) -> I won't. It's a classical fallacy: no need to disprove an unproven claim, the burden of prove is on the one raising the claim.

I had a ~5 uur stopover in South Korea (Incheon). We were informed by the flight staff that due to South Korean law, stopovers always had to completely disembark and go through customs again. This included passengers who would be going back onto the same airplane.

Do you want information on specific countries or routes? Or just the names of some airports where it happens?

@Mayou36 The comment doesn’t just say, “Very common”, though; it says, “Very common, depending on the country you’ve landed in”, which is true worldwide. How common it is depends on which country you’re in, and in some countries, it’s very common – such as the US, where it’s more or less exceptionless.

@JanusBahsJacquet - And flights going through the USA are disproportionately common. Its airlines have about ten times as many flights as Brazil (#7), for instance, and probably several times as many flights as the bottom half of countries' national airlines combined. China and India are also up there.

First, remember that customs is for goods. Checks of passport and visas is usually called passport control or immigration.
It is always the case that you have to go through passport control in the US, and I believe there are a few other countries which do it as well: there is no sterile airside airport transit at all, everyone has to go through passport control, reclaim luggage, go through customs, and drop luggage for the next flight, even if checked through.
It is also the case in some airports which do not have sterile airside transit (usually smaller airports, but that includes quite busy airports like Luton in London for example, and a number of other airports used mostly by LCCs). But in those cases, airlines will usually not sell you connecting flights through those airports (so they are self-transfers).
Of course if you have a self-transfer and checked luggage you will need to go through passport control as well to retrieve your luggage and then go to departures to check in.
If you have multiple connections within the same country (or group of countries like the Schengen Area), it’s also a requirement to go through passport control at the first airport in the country/area and then through exit passport control at the last one.
This also applies when your arrival or departure airport is in the same country/area as the connection airport (and the other end of the itinerary isn’t). For instance if you fly JFK-FRA-ZRH you will go through checks in FRA, not ZRH (at least in theory — you could be subject to additional checks in ZRH even though you arrive from another Schengen Area country).
Same thing if you have to switch airports. Sometimes also if you have to switch terminals (may depend on the exact combination of terminals in some places).
In some airports, some transit passengers may also be isolated (right at the gate) and have their passports taken away during international transits. There could also be checks to ensure that they have an airside transit visa right at the gate, in situations which require one.
There’s also the case of US pre-clearance: if you fly to the US through an airport which has pre-clearance you will go through (US) passport control at that point (but you will then arrive in the US as a domestic flight without any checks there).
Without the details of the itinerary (origin and destination countries, all connection airports, the airlines involved, and whether this was a real connection or a self-transfer) it is difficult to say whether this was perfectly normal or if something went wrong, but I suspect the former rather than the latter. And if so, then, no, there’s no reason to complain.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

It is quite common and depends on multiple factors. We often travel from Canada to another country via the US and, during the return trip, it is almost always the case that we pass through customs and immigration. The one exception from memory was Bahamas to Canada via the US. The other way, we generally do the US control when leaving Canada at the Canadian airport.
Also, going from Canada to any country in Europe via any other European country forces this to happen since customs and immigration is done at the point of entry in the EU. Earlier this month, I transited via Amsterdam on the way to Oslo and had to do customs and immigration in the Netherlands. Similarly on the return trip.
Even in some countries that have international-to-international transfer facilities, it can happen that you still have to do immigration when changing terminals, if the airport does not have an internal connection between the two.
ADDENDUM
This answer starts saying that it depends on multiple factors which it does. It would be rather hard to list every possible connection and figure out exactly the probability distribution with all combination of routes, airports and terminals. So while it is possible to point out which sub-case of the generalization does not apply, the reality is that there are plenty of cases when this happens. Examples above are from recent travel but are not meant to be exhaustive.

To clarify, you had to go through customs in Netherlands on a trip from Norway-Netherlands-Canada? In that direction you are going Schengen to Schengen and then out.

@Damila No, the answer says "from Canada ...via Amsterdam on the way to Oslo", but that doesn't matter, it's the same both ways.

@Itai Are you sure you cleared customs in Amsterdam, and not just immigration? Because in the EU, customs are usually cleared at the final airport, not at the point of entry (in contrast to passport controls, that happen at the point of entry to the Schengen area). But then, Norway is not EU, so EU rules might not apply. So please, do not write "to any European country via any other European country", because Europe, the EU and the Schengen area are not the same and it really depends on the specific countries involved.

(+1) Minor nitpick: Immigration is only done at the point of entry in the Schengen area, which includes several non-EU countries (Iceland, Norway, Switzerland) but does not include Ireland and Cyprus (which are however EU member states).

@Sabine It used to be the case but that's not true anymore, you do clear customs for your hand luggage at the point of entry in the EU (and again at your final airport, after collecting any hold luggage). Usually it's discreet but it is definitely there in Amsterdam, right after the Schengen entry passport check (saw it this week going from pier E to pier C at Schiphol). Also saw it in Frankfurt a couple of years ago where it was even more visible: red and green lanes painted on the ground with an officer standing in the middle who challenged me about the contents of a duty free bag.

@Relaxed So the rule "your hand luggage is checked at the first point of entry" is now actually enforced? Admittedly, I haven't been outside the EU for a few years now - last time was 2019 - but while the internet always said that hand luggage would be checked at the first point of entry, I never saw this happening, only the "full check" including hold luggage at the final destination.

@Damita - When we come from Canada to the EU, customs is most often on the point of landing into Europe. So, yes.

@Sabine - Actually, I think it does apply, at least from Canada. When we land at any European country (Europe, EU or Schengen), immigration is done at that point, regardless of the next country within this group. Customs is almost always done at that point too but sometimes it is done (one must declare voluntarily since people are always funneled through customs automatically as in South America) again at the destination country. I have been to 25 European countries and entered at least 18 of those by air from Canada, I have a few data-points.

@Sabine - About the customs check. Yes. In fact, I had to exist the passenger area and back in. There was a customs path for those with something to declare, so I would have gone in, if I had to. So I did security and immigration too in Amsterdam.

@Sabine To a point. In Frankfurt, there was an officer standing who would randomly challenge people (and I was going around with a foreign duty free bag). In Amsterdam, there was a table, a scanner, and a sign but nobody in sight… which is also my experience of the final check in most cases. But you are, at least implicitly, clearing customs at the first airport.

@Itai That's not typical. What you experienced seems more akin to the check that's supposed to happen at your final destination in the EU. What pier / airline combinations were you using? In Amsterdam, as in other major hubs in Europe, it is often possible to transit without leaving the sterile transit area and in that case the customs check only covers your hand luggage.

@Relaxed. Even so, that still is customs even they only handle some of it. The question is if we have to pass through customs at the intermediate airport is often yes. The fact that you may have to do it again is extra. On some connections, you may not have to take your checked luggage in the intermediate stop but again it's not the point.

@Itai In the EU, you always have to clear customs at the first point of entry in the EU (not often, always) and you always have to do it again at your final destination (not sometimes, always). I don't know if that's “the point” but it seems relevant. The thing is that's the case even if you don't have to pick up your luggage and not merely because your connection didn't work as expected. That's why focusing on this rather atypical experience when it is in fact a much more general rule seems like a distraction.

Just FYI, the title and some of the question body replaced "custom" with "immigration check". Please check if the answer is still valid.


Is that a common practice in some countries to require everyone to be processed through customs, even if they have connecting flights to destinations outside that country?

Yes. It is standard practice in the US and Canada and a few smaller countries. The only exception for the US are so called pre-clearance airports, where you pass through US immigration at the departure airport. But you still need to go through immigration.

Did the passengers have any right to refuse it?

No. The responsibility of having the correct paperwork rests on the passenger and IATA offers online tools to help you do this. https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/passport-visa-health-travel-document-requirements.htm

Some of the passengers became very aggravated,

That sounds unlikely. Most passengers should know that this would happen and they MUST have proper documentation to enter the transit country otherwise the airline would not have allowed them to board in the first place.
There are always exceptions: sometimes there is an emergency or some other issue that triggers extra controls and unforeseen entry into the country, but these are handled on a case by case basis. It would help if you could add the details of where exactly that happened and which flights were involved.

Just FYI, the title and some of the question body replaced "custom" with "immigration check". Please check if the answer is still valid.

Yes, it's very common, especially when you aim for the cheapest flights. Always true if you go through the US or Canada. Sometimes if you're connecting to or from a discount airline you have to go through customs and immigration even if the airport has sterile transfer for other flights on the same airline or at the same terminal.
Certainly going through incoming and outgoing customs and immigration multiple times on one trip can be tiring and stressful with long queues and sometimes rude officials when your aim is just to GTFO.
Going on one ticket, avoiding countries without sterile transfer facilities, and either flying direct or connecting at a hub within your destination or origin country can avoid those hassles, but usually you pay a premium for it.
Sadly, those most interested in saving money (young and footloose, the self-employed etc.) are also those most likely to face hassles at the otherwise unnecessary inspections. But even those more "mature" can suffer from schlepping luggage and their carcasses  through long queues, inspections, bag drops and back through the miserable security theatre yet again.
Regarding customs vs. immigration-- I'm hard-pressed to think of any time when they are not handled together- either both or none (including checked luggage). Sometimes (as in pre-clearance) it seems like they're not, but they are.

Just FYI, the title and some of the question body replaced "custom" with "immigration check". Please check if the answer is still valid.
